# input String by Console

Tags: java

I need a code to write String in the console and making compare with Array.

```
String Array = {"skill"};
Console co=System.console();
```

then compare Array with co...

Comment: The first line of your sample code doesn't compile, making it hard to tell what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: you right my English not good better must I say I tried to write code for inputing data by console and making compare with an Array.

Comment: Your **code** will not compile. It doesn't help that your English isn't good either - you haven't explained *how* you want to compare the user input with the array - but I was mostly commenting on the code...

Comment: Ok first can you tell me how I can input String by console ?

Comment: `System.in.readLine()`? Or `Console.readLine()`? How much of the `Console` API did you look at before asking us?

Comment: He wanted to ask something like this:   
    `var stringArray = new[] { "skillFirst", "skillSecond" };`    

    `var consoleInput = Console.ReadLine();`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

here is an example to read a string from the keyboard and compare the string with another string

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Main
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        String input = null;
        String compareString = "hello world";
        Scanner inputReader = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("please enter: hello world" );

        // here is how you take the input from keyboard

        input = inputReader.nextLine();
                // this is how you write to console
        System.out.println("You entered :" + input);

        //Here is how you compare two string
        if(compareString.equals(input))
        {
            System.out.println("input is: hello world");
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("input is not: hello world");
        }
    }
}
```

Execution1:

```
Please enter: hello world
```

Input:

```
hello world
```

output:

```
You entered :hello world
input is: hello world
```

Execution2:

```
Please enter: hello world
```

Input:

```
hello
```

output:

```
You entered :hello 
input is not: hello world
```